# Convergence of sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ to $f$ in $L^p$ if and only if $\|f_n\| \to \|f\|$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions in $L^p( [0,1])$, $1 \leq p < \infty$, which converges almost everywhere to a function $f$ in $L^p$. Show that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ in $L^p$ norm if and only if $\|f_n\| \to \|f\|$.

What does $\|f_n\| \to \|f\|$ mean and which convergence theorem is this? I know $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ in $L^p$ norm means

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \|f_n - f\|_p = 0 $$

Comment: Exercise 4.17 in Brezis' text "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations" walks you through this if you are interested. Also, $\|f_{n}\|_{p}\to \|f\|_{p}$ is usually referred to convergence **of** norm which deals with the convergence of the sequence of norms $(\|f_{n}\|_{p})_{n\geq 1}$, whereas $\|f_{n}-f\|_{p}\to 0$ is referred to convergence **in** norm. The latter is a stronger statement as it clearly implies the former, where as the converse is not true.

Comment: Thanks @OliverDiaz that is helpful

Answer (score 5):

It means that $\|f_n\|_p \to \|f\|_p$ in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints for a proof: Let $\|f_n\|_p \to \|f\|_p$. Now $2^{p}(|f|^{p}+|f_n|^{p} -|f_n-f|^{p})$ is non-negative and an application of Fatou's Lemma to this gives $\lim \sup \int |f_n-f|^{p} =0$. The converse part is true for any norm.

Comment: Fatou's lemma tells us $$2 \int |f|^p \le \lim \inf \int (|f_n|^p + |f|^p - |f_n-f|^p).$$ But where do you go from here? $\lim \inf$ is super-additive, so we can split things up nicely. Presumably, we want to rearrange the inequality in Fatou's lemma to get something like $$\lim \sup |f_n-f|^p \le \lim \inf |f_n|^p - |f|^p.$$ But I don't see how to rearrange the inequality.

Comment: It is given that $\|f_n\| \to \|f\|$ So $\lim \inf \int |f_n|^{p} =\lim  \int |f_n|^{p} =\int |f|^{p}$.

Comment: Yes, I know that that holds true. But how do you split up $\lim \inf \int (|f_n|^p + |f|^p - |f_n-f|^p)$?